# capture onPaste and pass the event to a function javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this might seem a very dumb question but i cant seem to figure out how to capture the `onPaste` event, and pass it on to a function to process.

```
$("input").on({
  'paste': function getdata(e) {

   var value = getdata();
   alert("you pasted" + value);
},
   'keyup': function getdata(e) {

    var value = getdata();
    alert("you pasted" + value);
}

});


function getdata(e) {
    if(window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) {
        value = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    } else if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData && e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData) {
        value = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    }

    return value; 

}
```

Comment: Just learnt something about passing maps to #on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you've given your event handler a name:

```
$("input").on({
  'paste': function getdata(e) {

   var value = getdata();
   alert("you pasted" + value);
   ....
});
```

You've called the event handler `getdata`. When you call `getdata()` inside the function, it therefore runs the event handler again. This obviously results in an infinite loop.

Remove the named function expression:

```
$("input").on({
  'paste': function (e) {

   var value = getdata(e);
   alert("you pasted" + value);
   ....
});
```

Two other corrections to your code.

First, you don't define `value` in `getdata`. You need to start the function with `var value;`

Second, you don't pass the event to `getdata`. You need to call it with `getdata(e)`.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/2YaJ4/2/) shows your code working perfectly.